# What will happen to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.* namespace in ASP.NET 5.0?

Tags: naming-conventions, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

[.NET 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/) will replace .NET Core 3.x when it is released in November—and, thus, [ASP.NET 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-preview-8/) will replace ASP.NET Core 3.x.

> ***Edit:*** This question is based on a fundamentally incorrect assumption. While the next version of .NET Core will, in fact, be .NET 5.0, the next version of ASP.NET Core will be ASP.NET Core 5.0. See the answers from [@Camilo-Terevinto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63745817/3025856) and [@omajid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63746519/3025856) for details.

Despite this, as of [Preview 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-8/) (8.20414.8), packages, assemblies, and namespaces still contain `AspNetCore` in their names. For example, see the following NuGet packages:

- [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8)
- [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8)
- [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8)
- [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language/5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8)

If you go to the documentation for e.g. the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-5.0) on learn.microsoft.com, however, you'll be redirected back to the ASP.NET Core 3.1 documentation with the warning:

> The requested page is not available for ASP.NET Core 5.0 Preview. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.

***Question:*** *Do we have any evidence of what these packages, assemblies, and namespaces will be named in the .NET 5.0 release?* Will they remain `Microsoft.AspNetCore` for backward compatibility, as the current *namespaces* suggest? Will they become `Microsoft.AspNet` for consistency with the product name, as the *documentation* suggests? Or does this remain TBD?

---

*Background:* Like other developers, I am working on the .NET 5.0 version of an open source library, and we aim to follow the same naming conventions as the underlying framework for the sake of familiarity, discovery, and consistency.

Comment: I didn't comment on the namespace issue on my answer because it seems like there's an issue in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and, thus, ASP.NET 5.0 will replace ASP.NET Core 3.x.

That is not accurate, **ASP.NET Core 5.0** will replace **ASP.NET Core 3.x**. The moniker that will change is .NET Core to .NET. [Migration guide ASP.NET Core 3.x to ASP.NET Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

Basically:

- .NET Framework 4.8 -> .NET 5
- .NET Core 3.1 -> .NET 5
- ASP.NET Core 3.1 -> ASP.NET Core 5

Comment: Thank you so much! I mentioned this on [another thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400924/net-5-0-and-asp-net-5-0-tags), but I've read the release notes on every single preview release of ASP.NET Core 5.0, and completely overlooked that they consistently label it ASP.NET Core 5.0, not ASP.NET 5.0. It's remarkable how our brains can see exactly what they expect to see if we're not reading with a critical eye.

Comment: @JeremyCaney no, it's a concerted marketing effort to make people believe that .NET 5 is somehow an upgrade of .NET Old, not the .NET Core version that actually replaces .NET Old.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That's exactly _why_ I expected that it would be ASP.NET 5 and not ASP.NET Core 5! I don't mind the marketing decision to rename it to .NET 5. I just find it confusing that ASP.NET still maintains the "Core".

Comment: @JeremyCaney what about ASP.NET MVC 5 then? The same version number would end up referring to both .NET Old and .NET Core stacks. There are a lot of ASP.NET technologies whose versions would conflict with ASP.NET Core. Finally, ASP.NET Core could run on .NET Old as well as .NET Core up to version 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

> thus, ASP.NET 5.0 will replace ASP.NET Core 3.x.

No, it won't. It's an unfortunate point of confusion, but it's not true.

Let me [quote David Fowler](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/19930#issuecomment-671409466), who is one of the [ASP.NET Core architects](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Careers-Behind-the-Code/Becoming-the-ASPNET-Architect-with-David-Fowler):

> There's no plan to change asp.net core to asp.net.

.NET Core becomes .NET 5, but ASP.NET Core stays as ASP.NET Core.