# How to pass a Logger to the Startup class in an ASP.NET 5.0 app?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-5

In ASP.NET 5.0, we can now [define a factory method for controlling the activation of the Startup class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-5.0?view=aspnetcore-5.0#control-startup-class-activation).

In the demo example provided by Microsoft, they create a logger and then pass this into the Startup class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = CreateLogger(); // <--- HERE !!!!

        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHost(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseStartup(context => new Startup(logger)); // Logger passed into the ctor
            })
            .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how the author created the Logger (ie. the code in that method), which hopefully will be an `ILogger`.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement the `ILogger` interface? Something like described in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#console (*Create the custom logger* section)? Or am I missing the question entirely?

Comment: ASP.NET 5 doesn't exist and it will never exist. ASP.NET Core 5 is what you are using.

Comment: Sorry, @CamiloTerevinto but .net core is now just .net with the 5.0 release

Comment: @Buildstarted Correct, .NET Core 3 -> .NET 5. However, ASP.NET Core 3 -> ASP.NET Core 5. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63733500/what-will-happen-to-the-microsoft-aspnetcore-namespace-in-asp-net-5-0/63745817#63745817

Comment: Well isn't there egg on my face, @CamiloTerevinto :)

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am not sure how the author created the Logger (ie. the code in that method), which hopefully will be an `ILogger`.

It's the same as always (fortunately). First, create and configure a logger factory:

```
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { /*configure*/ });
```

Then, get a logger out of it:

```
var startupLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
```

The above is just one way and there are multiple, both built-in and with the several third-party logging frameworks. Read more in the main [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#logging-providers-1) document.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wire it up in **ConfigureLogging** (Namespace: ***Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting***) extension:

```js
        private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddNLog(); //<-I used Nlog for demonstration purposes. This will take care things for you.
                //builder.AddConsole();
                //builder.AddDebug();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseStartup<Startup>(); //<Startup class
            });
```

Use dependency injection via your constructor:

```
private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;
public Class1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    this.loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
}

public SomeMethod(){
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Exception logger"); //<-You can call create logger here
}
```

- I would suggest you decide first, which logging framework you want to use, popular loggers provides rich documentations that will help you hit the ground running.